# boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer `cancel` behavior

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost-asio

Assume there is `asio`'s `deadline_timer` or similar, it expires and the callback is invoked. During the invocation and while the callback is still running the `cancel` is called.
The question is the `cancel` gonna block until the callback finishes?

Comment: That's a very good question. I think that `cancel` has been deprecated for a reason. And a reason would be canceling any async operation without blocking and waiting the callback, which in addition led to an unexpected behaviour. Even their [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer/cancel.html) suggests using non-error code overload. But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: just checked a second ago, it is not blocking, so your callback would wreak havok on stuff you try to execute. And BTW, I'm using the non-ec overload... Thats  quite disappointing since I have to (for reasons too long to explain) wait on timer destruction to block until there is no operations in flight, neither scheduled nor already executing

Comment: `deadline_timer` is not thread-safe, so calling `cancel` concurrently is UB. Or do you mean some other scenario?

Comment: @IgorR. any link to support your claim? consider following scenario, you have `basic_waitable_timer`. you set timeout, by using `spawn`, `wait` asynchronously and then, even from the same thread you call `cancel` sounds legit for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, cancel doesn't block and also doesn't wait for any handlers to have completed.

It is your responsibility to synchronize access to the timer instance if access is from different threads.

The limited threadsafety is documented here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer.html#boost_asio.reference.basic_waitable_timer.thread_safety

Comment: Just to make it clear, If one thread calls `expires_after` and another calls `clear` both should be performed under lock?